# how to find the grammar (production rules) for this?

Tags: context-free-grammar

Let S → ababa | aabaabaa| aaabaaabaaa | aaaabaaaabaaaa | ……

- find the Production Rules?

I've tried like 50 rules, but I can't seem to find the right ones.
can I please get a hint on how to start?

Comment: Could you give an example or two of the rules you have tried?

Comment: (S → aAbaAbaA  && 
  A → Aa | ε )     

but the problem is, this allows abaabaaa for example.  

and that's the main problem that i can't solve, which is how can i make sure that i have the same number of (a's)

Comment: Wouldnt the pumping lemma for CFL's prove that this is not generated by a CFG?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that it's not a context-free language?  Not all languages are, right?

Comment: It looks a lot like $0^n1^n2^n$, which is the canonical example of a non-CF language.